# How to connect HSQL DB Manager to a Embedded Database

Tags: hsqldb

Hi i'm connection my HSQL Embedded db using HSQL Database manager using hsqldb-2.3.3.jar.
But when i connected with the db i can't see any tables.
The application working good and i can even tables values while running app.
[image: My project structure]

[image: HSQL Manager Connection settings]

[image: After Connection]

Comment: Add `\learn_ware` to the end of the URL.

Comment: thanks it's worked..

Answer (score 0):

Each HSQLDB file: database has a name. The files for the database all have this name but different extensions.

I this example the database name is `learn_ware` and it is stored in `learn_ware.script` and `learn_ware.properties`.

To connect to a file database, append the database name (without an extension) to the path of the database directory.